# python interpreter exits automatically on "python"

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, interpreter

I usually use sublime to run my code, but when I try to use the interpreter (both in cmd and powershell)  it opens python and then immediately exits without any input from me.

```
eg:
PS C:\Users\Lahoa\Documents> python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
PS C:\Users\Lahoa\Documents>
```

As you can see it opens python(successfully), then exits without me being able to do anything. Has anyone seen this before? When I google I only find help regarding running scripts that close automatically on finish...

Thank you for any input

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run `C:\full\path\to\python.exe`? If not, `python` might be a function, script, or something else that Windows would execute first.

Comment: Try `python -i` to force interactive mode.

Comment: Thanks for tips, but same error. I have tried both full path and -i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. We have a script that adds various paths for various extra packages at my work. I found an error in one of the imports, which caused python to fail but wasnt giving an error message due to a try statement in the script.